# How to write the L-shaped symbol in latex?

Tags: symbols

I want to write the following equation in latex but dunno what's that L-shaped symbol.
[image]

I tried "\llcorner", but this is not what I exactly want... It looks like the following image:
[image]

I also tried [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/) and read the [great, big list of latex symbols](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf), but couldn't find it. So, any help is definitely appreciated.

Comment: Good list of resources here: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#HD.495

Comment: @Davislor Thank you so much.

Comment: @Yasinowski It is generally a good idea to wait a little while before accepting an answer; in this case, you also have an answer that shows the symbol that's already available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be built from `\rule`s.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxupr]{mathalpha}
\newcommand*{\Lcorner}{%
    \mathchoice%
        {\mathrel{\makebox[7pt][c]{\rule{.4pt}{7.5pt}\rule{5pt}{.4pt}}}}%
        {\mathrel{\makebox[7pt][c]{\rule{.4pt}{7.5pt}\rule{5pt}{.4pt}}}}%
        {\mathrel{\makebox[5.5pt][c]{\rule{.4pt}{5.25pt}\rule{3.5pt}{.4pt}}}}%
        {\mathrel{\makebox[4pt][c]{\rule{.4pt}{3.75pt}\rule{2.5pt}{.4pt}}}}%
}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tan}{Tan}

\begin{document}
\(\displaystyle \Lcorner\)
\(\textstyle \Lcorner\)
\(\scriptstyle \Lcorner\)
\(\scriptscriptstyle \Lcorner\)

\(\displaystyle \Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner F(E), y ) = DF(x)[\Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner E, x)]\)

\(\textstyle \Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner F(E), y ) = DF(x)[\Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner E, x)]\)

\(\scriptstyle \Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner F(E), y ) = DF(x)[\Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner E, x)]\)

\(\scriptscriptstyle \Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner F(E), y ) = DF(x)[\Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner E, x)]\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this complete guide. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 11):

The symbol is `\rightangle`, and is in `unicode-math` or the legacy packages `stix`, `stix2`, `mathdesign`, `fdsymbol`, and a few others.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with unicode-math alone. It was present only in fdsymbol. The OPs symbol is slightly taller that it is wide. fdsymbol \right angle looked as tall as it was wide.

Comment: @AJN Which version of `unicode-math`? It’s definitely in 0.8q.

Comment: V 0.81 I think. But I now notice that unicode-math is for lualatex and zelatex engines.

Comment: @AJN Ah! That’d explain it.

Answer (score 5):

Picture mode to the rescue. The symbol correctly changes size in the various math styles as well as in different font sizes.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e,mathrsfs}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Lcorner}{\mathbin{\mspace{1mu}\text{\L@corner}\mspace{1mu}}}
\newcommand{\L@corner}{%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\fontcharht\font`T}%
  \begin{picture}(0.8,1)
  \roundcap
  \Line(0,1)(0,0)(0.8,0)
  \end{picture}%
}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathOperator{\Tan}{Tan}

\begin{document}

\(\displaystyle \Lcorner\)
\(\textstyle \Lcorner\)
\(\scriptstyle \Lcorner\)
\(\scriptscriptstyle \Lcorner\)

\(\displaystyle \Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner F(E), y ) = DF(x)[\Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner E, x)]\)

\(\textstyle \Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner F(E), y ) = DF(x)[\Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner E, x)]\)

\(\scriptstyle \Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner F(E), y ) = DF(x)[\Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner E, x)]\)

\(\scriptscriptstyle \Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner F(E), y ) = DF(x)[\Tan^k( \mathscr{H}^k \Lcorner E, x)]\)

{\Large $A\Lcorner B$} {\footnotesize $A\Lcorner B$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I reused the [code by Vincent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/547959/4427).